# Chrome on PC using <input file="file" name="file" multiple>

Tags: google-chrome, haml, erb

I am trying to do a multiple input field across all browsers (except IE) and I am having trouble with Chrome from a PC. The problem is not that Chrome doesn't support input multiple, it is that Chrome ignores multiple when I put it into a tag, UNLESS it is just a .html file. For .html.erb, .html.haml, and .html.slim, it ignores the multiple part.

This code for slim:

`input{type="file" name="file" class="native-file-input" multiple="multiple"}`

This code for haml:

`%input{type: "file", name: "file", class: "native-file-input", multiple: "multiple"}`

and this code for erb:

`<input type="file" name="file" class="native-file-input" multiple>`

Those all produce:

`<input class=​"native-file-input" name=​"file" type=​"file" >​`

in the Chrome browser on PC. I don't understand why it won't add multiple. If I inspect the element and add multiple to the end, then I can input multiple files. So, it is clear to me that Chrome supports multiple, there is just some bug getting Chrome to create multiple from .erb, .haml, or .slim. Also, all this work on Mac no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in other browsers multiple: 'some_string' validates to true but typically you want this:

```
%input{type: "file", name: "file", class: "native-file-input", multiple: true}
```